# Cannot call value of non-function type 'SessionManager'

Tags: swift, session, swift3, migration, alamofire

I'm trying to migrate someone else's code up to Swift 3. All went quite well, except for one line I haven't been able to figure out. It works fine in Swift 2.2 as is, but won't compile in Swift 3. It returns the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'SessionManager'

```
import Alamofire

struct AlamofireAPIManager {
    static let sharedManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 360 // 120 seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 360
        return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()
}

.
.
.

override init() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 360
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 360 // seconds

    self.alamofireManager = AlamofireAPIManager.sharedManager(configuration)
}
```

The line in question is:

```
self.alamofireManager = AlamofireAPIManager.sharedManager(configuration)
```

If I change it to:

```
self.alamofireManager = AlamofireAPIManager.init()
```

it will compile, but then the app doesn't work correctly.

Do you have any idea what he's trying to do, here, and what should be done to migrate it to Swift 3? Thanks.

** Edit: Here is the original code, before any migration:

```
import Alamofire

struct AlamofireAPIManager {
    static let sharedManager: Manager = {
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 360 // 120 seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 360
        return Manager(configuration: configuration)
    }()
}

.
.
. 

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 360
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 360 // seconds

self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: Why are you passing a parameter to sharedManager variable? SessionManager is not a function, as the error says.

Comment: Not really sure, @mattd. As I said, I'm working on someone else's code. The original command was actually `self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)`. It got changed a few times during migration. I am assuming that it's attempt to share a session manager.

Comment: Yes, it's a singleton variable. And so it doesn't accept parameters, because you are set them inside the variable declaration.
Basically, you should remove parameter inside you call and the two versions are the same.

Comment: If I change it to `self.alamofireManager = AlamofireAPIManager.sharedManager` or `self.alamofireManager = AlamofireAPIManager.sharedManager()`, it won't compile. The only thing I could get to compile is `self.alamofireManager = AlamofireAPIManager.init()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is compiling:

```
import AlamoFire

struct AlamofireAPIManager {
    static let sharedManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 360 // 120 seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 360
        return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()
}

func i() {
    let alamofireManager = AlamofireAPIManager.sharedManager
}
```